# Tag mismatch error-Android studio

Tags: android, xml

I have trying for hours surfing online almost through every link both on stack overflow and google, but I couldn't find a possible solution for the Tag Mismatch error!

I updated my android studio to the version 2.3 on ubuntu 16.04 lts. Before that it was working perfectly. During the download, an error occurred saying the tag mismatch and I couldn't download Intel x86 Atom Image. Later on, I found the same error saying that Gradle project sync failed, Tag Mismatch!

After trying almost everything I had to go for un-installing and installing again! To un-install I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546723/uninstall-android-studio-completely).

Then I to re-install I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu).

But still the same error with syncing.

If you need more info let me know!

Comment: I think you are not able to build your project ,right?

Comment: Before building I am not able to even sync/refresh at the beginning. So I cannot even build!

Comment: add your gradle

Comment: Do you mean build.gradle?

Comment: yes your module level gradle

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got this problem before, it's caused by an incomplete download of `gradle`.

Go to your `.gradle` folder, for me it's in `/home/myusername/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yvs/`, note your gradle filename (e.g., `gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`).

Go to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and download the zip file here (e.g., `gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`), then just replace the corrupted one with you downloaded file.

Comment: Had the same issue in Intellj, and rebuilding the project solved my problem.

Comment: After I deleted `.gradle` folder it started to show me this error. Previously I could delete `.gradle` folder in my user windows folder without any harm to free space (because this folder after sometime becomes quite large)

Comment: after doing all that I get `ERROR: Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)`

Comment: I deleted this folder again, rebooted Windows and it finally started to work

Comment: in windows we need to paste the downloaded file to this path: C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\<gradle version:gradle-5.1.1-all>\<failed folder:97z1ksx6lirer3kbvdnh7jtjg>

Comment: have the same error I'm downloading a new gradle but it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

This is a firewall problem. I had a similar problem and managed to solve it by disabling the firewall.

Comment: I achieved a similar solution by connecting to a VPN

Answer (score 4):

- I got this problem before, it's caused by an incomplete or incorrect download of gradle version.
- Change following line in gradle-wrapper.properties

  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`
- Click File --> Invalidate cache / Restart
- Then click on sync button to sync gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the dependency:

```
if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
} else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1+'
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.8'
    }
}
```

with:

```
if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
} else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2+'
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.8'
    }
}
```

You have to replace the version number of gradle only.

Comment: wow, this works well. In my situation I had android studio 3, and I have up dated to gradle version 3.3. So, wanting to open my old project when I was having A.Studio 2 and gradle version 2.1.3 it was throwing an exception. the part that I edited was classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'//I removed the + and put the old version I had

Answer (score 1):

I removed .gradle and .idea files and sync again then project synced successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, it was my `Kapersky` which prevent access to internet for my Android Studio.
I have `disabled` `Kaspersky`, it works like a charm :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, in my case, has been solved reinstalling Android Studio in the root directory of the system (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        }
    } else {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.8'
        }
    }
```

Make sure that you have in your .gradle the gradle version you are pointing to In my case 2.1.3 and add like the following. In my case the app was failing to download from jCenter due to the constructed download URL which was wrong based on my gradle settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Sync Project with Gradle Files". It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was actually caused by connectivity issues (switching from Zero Trust network to my mobile hotspot did the trick)...