# android studio give me error when I install android studio

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, error-handling, runtime-error

[here is error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0jzi.png)

hello everyone

I'm doing react native project or when I install android studio it's give me **error** which one I give above

first time I install then it's same error but I thing some thing miss in sdk installation but now I'm just install and run but it's give me error when I install studio

I don't know where is mistake

I'm try this thing [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802270/tag-mismatch-error-android-studio) [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiqOCg_10n0) it also not working

anyone can give me solution

thank you so much!!

Comment: try referencing this and see if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802270/tag-mismatch-error-android-studio

Comment: I don't know how to do this

Comment: it's not working in my

Comment: have you come across this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/32629580/15289747 ? Maybe this could be helpful.

Comment: it's also not work I'm try all those thing

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I "solved" it:
1)Delete your ~/. Android* folders (losing all of your settings :/).
2)Run Android Studio. ...
3)Click the X on the wizard window. ...
4)Go to Settings->Project Defaults->Project Structure and change the Android SDK location to the correct one.

Comment: I don't understand your answer please explain deeply

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).